# I want to populate an array [ ] , with a spread syntax by a given number of times

Tags: javascript, class, concatenation, template-literals, spread-syntax

So I have a var size that may vary which counts how many arrays are passed in an argument.

```
concatenate(...arg){
 let size = arg.length ;
}
```

I want to use spread syntax by a number of times equal with that size ,more specific I want to concatenate all arrays, for example :

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3];
let arr2 = [3,2,1];
let arr3 = [4,5,6];
// unknown number of array

let finalArr = [...arr1,...arr2,...arr3,...etc];
```

So what I want to ask you is to replace the hardcoded finalArr, with a template that can take care of that for me?

What I tried so far :

```
// Arrays share the same content,ex : Arr : {content:[Arr(3)}
function concatenate(...arg){
 let size = arg.length;
 let arrays = arg;
 let tmplt = Arr(size+1).join(`Arr${size}`);
 let finalArr = [];
 while(size>=0){
  finalArr= [tmplt];
  size--;
}
return finalArr;
}

//input
let var1 = [{content:[2,9,10]}];
let var2 = [{content:[3,1,3]}];
let var3 = [{content:[9,1,8]}];
var1.concatenate(var2,var3);

// expected output
[2,9,10,3,1,3,9,1,8]
```

Finally, I try to reproduce the concat() method of Array within a class List that I made. The rules are : no Array.prototype.methods() allowed .
Full code so far :

```
 class List {
  constructor(items){
   this.content = !items ? [] : items;
   this.size = this.length();
 }
 length(arg=0){
  let size = arg;
  if(!this.content[arg]){
   return size;
 }
  size++;
 return this.length(size);
 }
 append(arg){
  if(this.size ==0 && this.size == arg.size){
   this.content = new List();
   return this.content;
 }
 this.content = [...this.content,...arg.content] 
 return this.content;
 }
 concatenate(...arg){ 
  let test = arg;
  let size = 0;
  let final = [];
  while(test[size]!=undefined){
  // final += [...test[size].content];
  size++;
  let x = Array(size+1).join(`...test${size}.content`);
  while(size>=0){
    size--;
   
     }
    }

   }

  }

  let aList = new List([2,9,10]);

  let anotherList = new List([3,14,1]);

  let thirdList = new List([9,0,8]);

  aList.concatenate(anotherList,thirdList);
```

Comment: If you click `[<>]` snippet editor, you can post your [mcve] here instead of codepen

Comment: If you can't use array methods why are you using `join` in your example?

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/1qy8n6ke/

Comment: what do you mean with not using array methods? please add a concise example of given data and wanted result.

Comment: You've also not made a class, you've made a function.

Comment: Join should not be used either. Agree :) ! I share full code so you can check class implementation . @Andy

Comment: Exercise come's from a study enviorment called Exercism . Here is the link  with full instructions: https://exercism.io/tracks/javascript/exercises/list-ops/solutions/d7b567006e744f92b5c578937f6bc212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [a generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) which takes arrays [delegates to each of the iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*). This allows you to flatten as many arrays as you want and can be used with spread notation:

```js
function* concat(...arrays) {
  for (const array of arrays)
    yield* array;
}

function concatenate(...arg){
 return [...concat(...arg)];
}


let arr1 = [1,2,3];
let arr2 = [3,2,1];
let arr3 = [4,5,6];

let finalArr = concatenate(arr1, arr2, arr3);

console.log(finalArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: It is the answer that i was looking for ! Thank you . Also forced me to inform myself about iterators/generators function .

Answer (score 0):

You could take nested for loops.

```js
function concatenate(...args) {
    const result = [];
    for (const array of args) for (const { content } of array) result.push(...content);
    return result;
}

const
    var1 = [{ content: [2, 9, 10] }],
    var2 = [{ content: [3, 1, 3] }],
    var3 = [{ content: [9, 1, 8] }];

console.log(...concatenate(var1, var2, var3)); // [2, 9, 10, 3, 1, 3, 9, 1, 8]
```

Comment: `push` is an array method, and they are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method on arrays to concatenate them.

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3];
let arr2 = [3,2,1];
let arr3 = [4,5,6];

function concatenate(...arg){
 let size = arg.length ;
  let finalArr = [];
  
  for(let i = 0; i < size; i++)
    finalArr.push(...arg[i]);
  return finalArr
}

finalArr = concatenate(arr1, arr2, arr3);
console.log(finalArr);
```

Comment: _“The rules are: no `Array.prototype.*` methods allowed.”_